# How to scale a canvas from within a list item?

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas, html-lists

I created a 3D model with Zdog which resizes based on the size of the screen.  This works as expected:

```js
const TAU = Zdog.TAU;

let hat = new Zdog.Illustration({
  element: '.zdog-canvas', // set canvas with selector
  dragRotate: true,
  rotate: {x: TAU/4, z: TAU/-6},
    translate: {y: 20},
  zoom: 4,
    onResize: function( width ){
              this.zoom = width / 300;
          }
});


var dome = new Zdog.Hemisphere({
  addTo: hat,
  diameter: 80,
  stroke: 20,
  color: 'blue',
  fill: true,
});

var brim = new Zdog.Ellipse({
  addTo: dome,
  width: 95,
  height: 73,
  quarters: 2,
  stroke: 20,
  translate: {y: 34},
  rotate: {z: TAU/4},
  fill: true,
  color: 'blue'
});

function animate() {
  hat.rotate.z += 0.03;
  hat.updateRenderGraph();
  // animate next frame
  requestAnimationFrame( animate );
}

animate();
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
}

.myDiv{
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.zdog-canvas {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  background: #FDB;
  cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/zdog@1/dist/zdog.dist.min.js"></script>

<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div class='myDiv'>
                <canvas class="zdog-canvas" width="800" height="500"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, if I place this 3d model inside of a list item, then the 3d model overflows past the bottom of the screen instead of scaling for the height of the list item.  My goal is ultimately to have a list item which contains the 3d model on the left, and some text describing it on the right.  How can I fix this, so that when the model is placed inside of a list item tag, it scales relative to the height of the list item?

```js
const TAU = Zdog.TAU;

let hat = new Zdog.Illustration({
  element: '.zdog-canvas', // set canvas with selector
  dragRotate: true,
  rotate: {x: TAU/4, z: TAU/-6},
    translate: {y: 20},
  zoom: 4,
    onResize: function( width ){
              this.zoom = width / 300;
          }
});


var dome = new Zdog.Hemisphere({
  addTo: hat,
  diameter: 80,
  stroke: 20,
  color: 'blue',
  fill: true,
});

var brim = new Zdog.Ellipse({
  addTo: dome,
  width: 95,
  height: 73,
  quarters: 2,
  stroke: 20,
  translate: {y: 34},
  rotate: {z: TAU/4},
  fill: true,
  color: 'blue'
});

function animate() {
  hat.rotate.z += 0.03;
  hat.updateRenderGraph();
  // animate next frame
  requestAnimationFrame( animate );
}

animate();
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
}

.myIcon{
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.zdog-canvas {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  background: #FDB;
  cursor: move;
}

li{
  width: 100%;
  height: 20vh;
  background: red;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/zdog@1/dist/zdog.dist.min.js"></script>

<html>

<body>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class='flexbox-container'>
          <div class='myIcon'>
            <canvas class="zdog-canvas" width="800" height="500" />
          </div>
          <h1>some text</h1>
        </div>
        <div class='flexbox-container'>
          <div class='myIcon'>
            <canvas class="zdog-canvas" width="800" height="500" />
          </div>
          <h1>some text</h1>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```js
const TAU = Zdog.TAU;

let hat = new Zdog.Illustration({
  element: '.zdog-canvas', // set canvas with selector
  dragRotate: true,
  rotate: {x: TAU/4, z: TAU/-6},
    translate: {y: 20},
  zoom: 4,
    onResize: function( width ){
              //console.log('adjusted width ')
              this.zoom = width / 300;
          }
});


var dome = new Zdog.Hemisphere({
  addTo: hat,
  diameter: 80,
  stroke: 20,
  color: 'blue',
  fill: true,
});

var brim = new Zdog.Ellipse({
  addTo: dome,
  //diameter: 80,
  width: 95,
  height: 73,
  quarters: 2,
  stroke: 20,
  translate: {y: 34},
  rotate: {z: TAU/4},
  fill: true,
  color: 'blue'
});

//illo.updateRenderGraph();

function animate() {
  // rotate illo each frame
  hat.rotate.z += 0.03;
  hat.updateRenderGraph();
  // animate next frame
  requestAnimationFrame( animate );
}

animate();
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
}

.flexbox-container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.myIcon{
  flex: 1;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.text-div{
  flex: 1;
}

.zdog-canvas {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 20vh;
  background: #FDB;
  cursor: move;
}

.list-item{
  width: 100%;
  height: 20vh;
  background: red;
  color: black;
  margin: 1vw 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/zdog@1/dist/zdog.dist.min.js"></script>

<html>

<body>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li class="list-item">
        <div class='flexbox-container'>
          <div class='myIcon'>
            <canvas class="zdog-canvas" width="800" height="500" />
          </div>
          <div class="text-div"> stuff</div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="list-item">
        <div class='flexbox-container'>
          <div class='myIcon'>
            <canvas class="zdog-canvas" width="800" height="500" />
          </div>
          <div class="text-div"> stuff</div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```